# Why does feature selection decrease complexity, but it does NOT necessarily lead to improvement of accuracy?

Tags: feature-selection

Feature selection reduce size of a problem - reducing compute time and space required to run classification algorithms.

While feature selection does decrease complexity, it does NOT have to improve classification accuracy.

**Why does feature selection decrease complexity, but it does NOT necessarily lead to improvement of classification accuracy?** Can you provide papers for that?

Comment: feature selection necessarily involves throwing out information, so if not done carefully can lead to worse performance

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent standard normal random variables, and $Y$ is $1$ when $X_1 + X_2$ is positive and 0 otherwise, then a model with both $X_i$s can achieve perfect classification accuracy whereas a model with only one of the $X_i$s won't have enough information to do so.